# Add someone to contacts through Game Center?

Tags: ios, ipad, contacts, game-center

Is there a way to add the friends I have added to Game Center to my contacts app? I'm using iOS 7.1 on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this on any of the iOS device pages:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html or [/ipad.html](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html) or [/ipodtouch.html](http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipodtouch.html).